# Existence of the tangent plane to the graph

Tags: real-analysis

If the partial derivatives $f_x, f_y$ don't exist at $(0,0)$, does that imply that there is no tangent plane to the graph of $f$ at the point $(0,0,f(0,0))$?

Comment: Well, you could have a vertical tangent plane to a surface. If $f(x,y) = \sqrt{1 - (x-1)^2 - y^2}$ for $(x-1)^2 + y^2 \le 1$, I’m not sure if there’s a convention as to whether the tangent plane to the full sphere would be considered a tangent plane to the graph of the upper half sphere at that boundary.